# Await or not a sub function in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await

What is the difference between:

```
async function subfunc(){
    await something()
}

async function func(){
    subfunc() // subfunc is not awaited but something inside it is
}

func()
```

and

```
async function subfunc(){
    await something()
}

async function func(){

    await subfunc() // subfunc is awaited and something inside it is also
}

func()
```

It sounds like it produces the same result, where am I wrong?

Comment: if `subFunc` is not awaited, then the code from which `subFunc` is called will not wait for the asynchronous operation inside the `subFunc` to complete.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

Comment: @Yousaf this is what I don't get, we you execute subfunc without await, something() is awaited anyway no?

Comment: `someThing` is awaited inside `subFunc`, so `subFunc` will wait for the async operation inside `subFunc` to complete BUT `func` isn't waiting for `subFunc` to complete; by "completion", I mean the completion of the async operation inside `subFunc`. It is like a _chain_ of promises where one promise waits for the other promise to settle.

Comment: @FTG - Re [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308465/await-or-not-a-sub-function-in-javascript/75308554?noredirect=1#comment132885673_75308465), I thought it was worth adding to my answer to go into that point in a bit of detail. But Yousaf is quite correct (except it's not *like* a chain of promises, it *is* a chain of promises :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It sounds like it produces the same result, where am I wrong?

The results are **very** different.

Without `await`, the promise returned by `subfunc` is not awaited, so `func` settles its promise without waiting for the promise from `subfunc` to settle. Several ramifications of that:

- `subfunc`'s work won't be done yet when `func`'s promise is settled.
- `func` can't use the fulfillment value of `subfunc`'s promise (though your code using `await` doesn't use it either, so that may not matter to you).
- if `subfunc`'s promise is rejected, it doesn't cause rejection of `func`'s promise; `func`'s promise will *already* be fulfilled. In fact, nothing will handle the rejection of `subfunc`'s promise, which will at a minimum trigger a console warning about an unhandled rejction or at a maxiumum could terminate the process the code is running in (Node.js does this by default, for instance).

*(Re that third one: It happens that in the example you've given, nothing is handling rejection of `func`'s promise either, but at least code calling `func` has the opportunity to handle rejection. Without the `await` of `subfunc`'s promise, code calling `func` can't avoid a possible unhandled rejection.)*

You can see some of that in these two examples (be sure to look int he real browser console):

**Without** `await`:

```js
function something(flag) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (flag) {
                console.log("`subfunc` promise fulfilled");
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log("`subfunc` promise rejected");
                reject(new Error("Some error here"));
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function subfunc(flag) {
    await something(flag);
}

async function func(flag) {
    subfunc(flag); // No `await`
}

async function test(flag) {
    console.log("-");
    console.log(
        `Calling \`func\` to test ${flag ? "fulfillment" : "rejection"}:`
    );
    try {
        await func(flag);
        console.log("`func` promise fulfilled");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("`func` promise rejected: ", error.message);
    }
}

console.log("WITHOUT `await`:");
test(true).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        test(false);
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Notice the

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Some error here

or similar in the real browser console. That's the unhandled rejection.

**With** `await`:

```js
function something(flag) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (flag) {
                console.log("`subfunc` promise fulfilled");
                resolve();
            } else {
                console.log("`subfunc` promise rejected");
                reject(new Error("Some error here"));
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function subfunc(flag) {
    await something(flag);
}

async function func(flag) {
    await subfunc(flag);
}

async function test(flag) {
    console.log("-");
    console.log(
        `Calling \`func\` to test ${flag ? "fulfillment" : "rejection"}:`
    );
    try {
        await func(flag);
        console.log("`func` promise fulfilled");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("`func` promise rejected: ", error.message);
    }
}

console.log("WITH `await`:");
test(true).then(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        test(false);
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> this is what I don't get, we you execute `subfunc` without `await`, `something()` is awaited anyway no?

That's a very good observation. Yes, `something()` is `await`ed in `subfunc` (so `subfunc` doesn't settle its promise until the promise it gets from `something()` settles), but that doesn't make `func` wait for `subfunc` to settle *its* promise.

It may help to walk through the execution of your first code block (the one without `await` in `func`), starting where the main script calls `func`. *(Please note that I've omitted some details for clarity.)*

1. `func` calls `subfunc`:

   1. `subfunc` calls `something` and gets back a value, let's call it `pSomething`. (Let's assume the normal case: `pSomething` is a promise, and it's still pending.¹)
   2. `subfunc` uses `await` on `pSomething`:

      1. `subfunc` creates a promise, let's call it `pSubfunc`.
      2. `await` attaches fulfilment and rejection handlers to `pSomething`. (More on what these handlers do later.)
      3. `subfunc` returns `pSubfunc`.
   3. Now that `subfunc` has returned, `func` returns, since it's not doing anything with `subfunc`'s promise:

      1. `func` creates a promise (let's call it `pFunc`).
      2. `func` *fulfills* `pFunc` with `undefined`.
      3. `func` returns `pFunc`.
2. It's possible nothing further happens because `pSomething` is never settled, but let's assume at some point it gets fulfilled:

   1. `pSomething`'s settlement calls the fulfilment handler attached in `subfunc` in Step 1.2.2. That fulfilment handler contains the (implicit) code following the `await` in `subfunc`, which is `return;`. That code fulfills `pSubfunc` with `undefined`.

So as you can see, you're right that `pSomething` is `await`ed by `subfunc`, and so `pSubfunc` doesn't settle until `pSomething` settles. But `func` doesn't `await` `pSubfunc`, so `func` fulfills `pFunc` as soon as `subfunc` returns its still-pending promise.

And that's the crucial difference in the code: `func` doesn't wait for `subfunc` to finish its work, even though `subfunc` waits for `something` to finish its work.

¹ *If `pSomething` weren't a promise, `await` would create and fulfill a new promise using the non-promise value it received as the fulfilment value and use that instead, which would change a couple of minor details in the explanation above, but not in ways that your code could easily observe.*

Comment: regarding this point: "subfunc calls something and gets back a value, let's call it pSomething. (Let's assume the normal case: pSomething is a promise, and it's still pending.¹)" What about something() is more something like fetch().then().then(). Does i changes something to the reasoning? Now await fetch().then().then() is awaiting for a completion of something right? Even if subfunc is not awaited ?

Comment: @FTG - It depends on whether `something` *returns* the final promise created by that code (the one from the final `then`). If it does, then nothing changes, `something` still returns a pending promise. If it doesn't, then `something` either 1. Doesn't return a promise at all, or 2. Returns one that isn't waiting for that `fetch().then().then()` promise change to finish (in which case `something` behaves like `func` when it doesn't `await` `subfunc`'s promise -- it doesn't connect its promise to the one from that chain).

Comment: (I should say, it depends on whether `something` returns *some* promise that it waits to settle until the promise from that `fetch().then().then()` chain settles. It doesn't literally have to be the promise from the chain, just some promise that is dependent on it.)